# While trying to upload the CSV file through SSIS, the comma in the data is not being uploaded. What needs to be done?

Tags: ssis

Sample data from file

```
AllSource Division,AllSource Part Number,AllSource UOM,ALLSOURCE_DESC,QOE,Base UOM,Catalog Reject,Extra1,Extra2,Extra3,Extra4,Extra5,Extra6
CR Bard CH,000256,CA,"Button Adapter-Schlauchsystem Ernährung, 90°, kontinuierlich, für 18 F",12,EA,,,,,,,
CR Bard CH,000257,CA,"Button Adapter-Schlauchsystem Ernährung, gerade, Bolus, für 18 F",12,EA,,,,,,,
```

-- first row is the column names and I have given the two rows.
One with

`"Button Adapter-Schlauchsystem Ernährung, 90°, kontinuierlich, für 18 F"`

is one column under `ALLSOURCE_DESC`, here we have the column in the data.

While trying to upload it is behaving as one more column which is incorrect as per the file.
Could someone help me in this regard? I am trying this in SQL Server 2008 R2 edition.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your delimiter is comma, hence you column is reading the data after every comma causing addiational column in row one. you will need to change the delimiter in your file if you have comma as information in system.

Comment: In your connection manager, what have you defined as your text delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

in Flat File connection manager change text Qualifier to ", and the commas will be loaded as part of string.

I have tested the same on your sample file, below is the screen shot attached.
[image]

2. [image]

Comment: When you look at the second column, instead of 000256, it was 256 only, again I need to maintain the data as it is. The second column had only the number and no prefix 0's. The query used is: Insert into <tablename>
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENROWSET('MSDASQL',--provider name (ODBC)
     'Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};
        DEFAULTDIR=F:\Temp\;Extensions=CSV;CODEPAGE=OEM',--data source
  'SELECT * FROM [<filename>.csv]')

Comment: Could someone help me in this regard? I need to maintain the data as it is in the CSV file. The column integrity as well. While using OPENROWSET, I got the similar results as shown in the above picture.

Comment: change that particular column to Text, then it will hold leading Zero's.

Comment: no it didn't work. I tried the steps given by you in the File Connection Manager and it didn't work.

Comment: can u share your screen shots

Comment: sorry I couldn't do that. Could you please share your mail id I can send the screen shots through my personal mail id. There are some blocking from my work place.

Comment: satish37.lok@gmail.com